# Calculations with PyMongo

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I need to make a calculation based on MongoDB data. I tried looking at the API and I can't figure it out. For simplicity's sake, lets say that I want to take two variables (a & b) taken from a Document in MongoDB, and subtract them using Python.

JSON/MongoDB:

```
{
    "math" : {
        "variableone" : 3,
        "variabletwo" : 4,
    }
}
```

Python Code:

```
def calculation():
    variableone = 3                 #from MongoDB Document
    variabletwo = 4                 #from MongoDB Document
    sum = variableone - variabletwo
    print(sum)

calculation()
```

How would I be able to accomplish this?

Comment: Do you want to appy this to all document in your collection? Why don't you do this sever-side?

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have documents like:

```
{
    "math" : {
        "variableone" : 3,
        "variabletwo" : 4,
    }
}

{
    "math" : {
        "variableone" : 3,
        "variabletwo" : 4,
    }
}
```

you can iterate on them like:

```
for each in collection_name.find():
    var1 = each['math']['variableone']
    var2 = each['math']['variabletwo']
    sum = var1 + var2
    print(sum)
```

How above code works:

`collection_name.find_one` returns a cursor which you can use to iterate on all documents.

Then you access inner keys of document like a dict(or list. It depends on the structure of document).

for loop iterate on the cursor fetching each document one by one and storing the variables in local var1 and var2. Then you can operate on these local variables and print the sum or do whatever you want to do.

If you want use conditions while querying documents, you can use find() like:

```
collection_name.find({'math.variableone':3})
```